# error processing your request

Tags: magento2.3.0

I am using A2 Hosting and `Magento 2.3.0` when I tried to change the slider picture it shows an error **"There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.**

**Error log record number: 1382995242503**
Suggest a solution to my `problem`.

Comment: that message appears because you are in a default mode but when you try to change your mode into developer you will be able to see the exceptions in the browser. as for now, you can check it on the browser console

Comment: add error report

Answer (score 0):

To check the error log record, you can go and look up from this path:

> your_magento_root/var/log/exception.log

From there you can see what is the reason why you encounter such issue.

Answer (score 0):

For that, you need to check first what is the error. to enable error follow below steps.

**Run below command.**

> php bin/magento d:mode:set developer

Next, go to `app/bootstrap.php` and open this file and find below code on line number 11 approx.

```
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

To change with below

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Now you can see what is an actual error.

I hope it helps!

Comment: I am Using shared hoting on A2 Hosting